# HAProxy and reqrep Rewriting Configuration

Tags: haproxy

I'm trying to configurate Haproxy acl.
For example, `http://www.abc.com/test/test.html` rewrite to `http://www.abc.com/index.html`. Please tell me how to do? thanks

```
reqrep ^([^\ :]*)\ /test/test.html     \1\ /index.html
```

but the web server feedback:

> 502 Bad Gateway

The server returned an invalid or incomplete response.

Answer (score 3):

Configuration for your request should be like this:

```
reqrep ^GET\ /test/test.html\ HTTP/1.1 GET\ /index.html\ HTTP/1.1

default_backend dyn_server

backend dyn_server
mode http
server web1 ip:port
```

Hope this will helps you